# .net udplistener.receive acting inconsistently on hyperv vm vs host

Tags: c#, .net, udp, virtual-machine

I have a simple c# win forms app acting as a "collector" for syslog messages.  This is a snipit of the code in question.  This code "works fine" on a win7 and server 2019 machine in that the call to udplistener.receive blocks when there is nothing to receive (at least I thought that was how it was supposed to work ;)  But on a win7 hyperv vm and a server 2016 hyperv vm it doesn't block? It "receives" the same data infinitely.  I'm thinking its not clearing the buffer, so I added the debug prints, sure enough the second debug print is zero on "working" systems, but indeed is non zero on the systems that don't block.  I'm doing some more troubleshooting, not 100% sure its related to the VM's, wondering if others have seen similar? Is there a reason a VM would handle this differently?

```
MessageInfo("DEBUG: available before .Receive " + udpListener.Available.ToString());
bReceive = udpListener.Receive(ref anyIP);  
MessageInfo("DEBUG: available after .Receive " + udpListener.Available.ToString());
```

thanks
ben